# Unable to restrict editing rights with timestamp on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I am creating a google sheet where there are multiple users who need to enter the data at different time intervals. Every time they enter the data, there is an automatic timestamp to record when the data has been entered with date & time. I have used the below script for the timestamp. I have protected the timestamp range/column so that no one can make changes to it later. Now with this condition, when users are updating their tasks, the timestamp is not getting updated automatically. But as I remove the protection, the timestamp is working well.
Can someone please help how can I have timestamp & also ensure no one is able to edit it.

Script for timestampfunction

```
onEdit(event) { 
  var timezone = "IST";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"; // Timestamp Format
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);

  var range = event.range; // this will be the last cell edited
  var column = range.getColumn(); // use this to check the cell edited was in a relevant column
  var rangeValue = range.getValue(); // use this to check something was actually entered into the last cell edited
  var newRange  = range.offset(0,1); // this is one cell to the right of the last cell edited

  if ((column == 10|| column == 12|| column == 16|| column == 18|| column == 20|| column == 22|| column == 26|| column == 30|| column == 32|| column == 36|| column == 40|| column == 44) && rangeValue) { //if the last cell edited was in a relevant column, and there is a value in it
    newRange.setValue(date);
  } else if ((column == 10|| column == 12|| column == 16|| column == 18|| column == 20|| column == 22|| column == 26|| column == 30|| column == 32|| column == 36|| column == 40|| column == 44) && !rangeValue) { // there was no question or no response, so make sure there is no timestamp
    newRange.setValue("");
  }
}
```

Glimpse of the sheet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCZFY.png)

Answer (score 0):

### You need to replace the [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) `onEdit` trigger throuhg an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) one

Why?

- The simple trigger executes on behalf of the user who edits the sheet
- If the function running on trigger is meant to set values in a range that the user does not have permission to edit, the execution will fail
- An installable trigger will run on behalf of the user who created the trigger
- If the you as the main editor who is excluded from protections create the trigger, it will always run on your behalf, no matter which user performed an edit that fired the trigger